# Is there a way to hide all buttons on p5js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have a shop in a browser p5js game.

It's not important, but let's say the shop consists of:

`shopContents = { "Sushi": 5, "Boba": 6, "Watermelon": 3 }`

I have used a for loop to create a button for each of these items. Is there a way to hide each button in the shop at the press of a "back" button (with a `mousePressed()` function or something)?

I know it's possible to hard-code it with `sushiButton.hide()`, `bobaButton.hide()`, and `watermelonButton.hide()`, but I think it would be ridiculous if this was the only way to do it, especially if the shop has more than a handful of items.

Since the buttons are dynamically generated, and there could be many buttons in the end, is there a way to just hide all of the buttons?

**Edit:**

This is the Shop.js class:

```
class Shop { 
    constructor() {
        this.contents = {
            "Burger": 5,
            "Sushi": 10,
            "Hotpot": 20,
            "Boba": 6,
            "Burrito": 5
        };
        this.items = ["Burger", "Sushi", "Hotpot", "Boba", "Burrito"];
    }
}
```

This is the function I have in `sketch.js` which creates the buttons:

```
function openShop(){
    if (shop.items.length >= 1){
        for (let i = 0; i < shop.items.length; i++) {
            createButton(shop.items[i], shop.items[i])
                .position(625, width/2-i*25)
                .mousePressed(intermediateFunc(shop.items[i]));
        }
    }
}

function intermediateFunc(item) {
    console.log(item)
    return function() {
        getPrice(item);
    }
}

function getPrice(item) {
    console.log(shop.contents[item]) 
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide your code (as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) so that we can see what your codebase looks like?

Comment: @Samathingamajig I've just added it as an edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the buttons as an array in the `Shop` class, then iterate over all of them  and run the `.hide()` method.

```js
class Shop { 
    constructor() {
        this.contents = {
            "Burger": 5,
            "Sushi": 10,
            "Hotpot": 20,
            "Boba": 6,
            "Burrito": 5
        };
        this.items = ["Burger", "Sushi", "Hotpot", "Boba", "Burrito"];
        this.buttons = [];
    }
}

function openShop() {
    if (shop.items.length >= 1){
        for (let i = 0; i < shop.items.length; i++) {
            if (this.buttons.length > 0) { // if buttons are already made, just show them
                shop.buttons[i].show();
            } else {
                shop.buttons.push(createButton(shop.items[i], shop.items[i])
                    .position(625, width/2-i*25)
                    .mousePressed(intermediateFunc(shop.items[i]));
                );
            }
        }
    }
}

function closeShop() {
    for (let i = 0; i < shop.buttons.length; i++) {
        shop.buttons[i].show();
    }
}
```

However, you might want to use this style instead, since you're already using ES6+ classes:

```js
class Shop { 
    constructor() {
        this.contents = {
            "Burger": 5,
            "Sushi": 10,
            "Hotpot": 20,
            "Boba": 6,
            "Burrito": 5
        };
        this.items = Object.keys(this.contents); // This will always be the keys of this.contents, so do this to reduce hardcoded duplication
        this.buttons = this.items.map((itemName, idx) => {
            return createButton(itemName, itemName)
                    .position(625, width/2 - idx*25)
                    .mousePressed(intermediateFunc(itemName));
        });
    }

    open() {
        this.buttons.forEach((button) => button.show());
    }
    
    close() {
        this.buttons.forEach((button) => button.hide());
    }
}
```

And I would also recommend better utilizing the constructor to allow for many kinds of `Shop`s to be created without the `contents` hardcoded:

```js
class Shop { 
    constructor(contents) {
        this.contents = contents;
        this.items = Object.keys(this.contents);
        this.buttons = this.items.map((itemName, idx) => {
            return createButton(itemName, itemName)
                    .position(625, width/2 - idx*25)
                    .mousePressed(intermediateFunc(itemName));
        });
    }

    open() {
        this.buttons.forEach((button) => button.show());
    }
    
    close() {
        this.buttons.forEach((button) => button.hide());
    }
}

// Instantiate like this:
const shop = new Shop({
    "Burger": 5,
    "Sushi": 10,
    "Hotpot": 20,
    "Boba": 6,
    "Burrito": 5
});

// open shop
shop.open();

// close shop
shop.close();
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm pretty new to JavaScript and your suggestions are wonderful